# Django - Getting value from HTML dropdown menu + button

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I've done some searching already.

I have a program which will do some analysis based on a given country. The HTML form is:

```
<p>Select a country:</p>

<select form="countrySelection" id="countrySelect" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="BELGIUM">Belgium</option>
    <option value="FRANCE">France</option>
    <option value="ITALY">Italy</option>
</select>

<form action="/analysis" id="countrySelection" method="GET">
    <br>
    <input class="button" name="countrySubmit" type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
```

In my urls.py I have:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('analysis/', views.run, name='run'),
```

I want to get the value of the dropdown menu (BELGIUM/FRANCE/ITALY) *upon clicking the button* and then send it to the view **run**:

```
def run(request):

    country = ...

    [...]

    return HttpResponse("Completed.")
```

I tried to use "country = request.GET('countrySelection')" and got "TypeError: 'QueryDict' object is not callable" on that line, [due to name="countrySubmit" and value="Start"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9VOz.jpg). However, removing the tags results in "No GET data".

Comment: You need to put the form control within the <form> tag to get the value submitted.

Comment: Which form control?

Comment: `request.GET['countrySelection']` -- square brackets not round, as the error message says!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request.get('key') shoud be request.get['key'] as get is not a callable function. You also have to put your select inside the form. Here is the runnable code:

HTML:

```
<form action="/analysis" id="countrySelection" method="GET">
    <p>Select a country:</p>

    <select form="countrySelection" name="countrySelect" id="countrySelect" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="BELGIUM">Belgium</option>
        <option value="FRANCE">France</option>
        <option value="ITALY">Italy</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import get_template

# Create your views here.
def run(request):
    country = request.GET['countrySelect']
    print(country)
    return HttpResponse("Completed."+country)

def index(request):
   return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('analysis/', views.run, name='run'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the selected option without submitting the actual form, you can use `change event listener` from plain JavaScript.

```
var countriesOBject = document.getElementById("countrySelect");

activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // function/code to send the values to the back-end Django URL
    // "countriesOBject.value" will return the value of the select element

});
```